# Pickling set subclass raises unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, set, pickle, subclass

This code (using custom `list` subclass) works well for me:

```py
import pickle

class Numbers(list):
    def __init__(self, *numbers: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.extend(numbers)

numbers = Numbers(12, 34, 56)
numbers.append(78)

numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
```

but when I change the parent class to `set`:

```py
import pickle

class Numbers(set):
    def __init__(self, *numbers: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.update(numbers)

numbers = Numbers(12, 34, 56)
numbers.add(78)

numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
```

the code raises a `TypeError` with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
  File "test.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.update(numbers)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The `set` subclass is successfully initialized and works well but trying to pickle it raises a very confusing exception since **there is actually no `list` used in my code**.

Comment: I don't know exactly how `pickle` works, but it appears that `*numbers` shows up as a `list` (not a `tuple`?) somehow in the definition of `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your help. It appears that some other method inherited from the `set` (invoked by the `pickle` protocol) was initializing the class with `list` as first argument (the usual `set` behavior) and wasn't aware of my change in the constructor. The question did not receive much interest for some reason so after a couple of sleepless nights I kind of tackled it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

Modifying the constructor of a built-in type is hard and error-prone since other methods migth depend on it. Avoid whenever possible.

### Error inspection

First, by forcing the [Python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pickle.py) over the [compiled C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_pickle.c) of the `pickle` module we get more information in the traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1604, in _loads
    encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1086, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1437, in load_reduce
    stack[-1] = func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.update(numbers)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Although the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) states:

> When a class instance is unpickled, its `__init__` method is usually *not* invoked.

we can see from the traceback above that the `__init__` method *is* invoked if the pickled representation of the class contains the `REDUCE` opcode (generally when the class implements a custom [`__reduce__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__)) and, as the [inspection of the pickled representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html#command-line-usage) shows, the `REDUCE` opcode is indeed present:

```
 0: \x80 PROTO      3
 2: c    GLOBAL     '__main__ Numbers'
20: q    BINPUT     0
22: ]    EMPTY_LIST
23: q    BINPUT     1
25: (    MARK
26: K        BININT1    56
28: K        BININT1    34
30: K        BININT1    12
32: K        BININT1    78
34: e        APPENDS    (MARK at 25)
35: \x85 TUPLE1
36: q    BINPUT     2
38: R    REDUCE
39: q    BINPUT     3
41: }    EMPTY_DICT
42: q    BINPUT     4
44: b    BUILD
45: .    STOP
```

### Solution

Avoid modifying the constructor:

```py
import pickle

class Numbers(set):
    pass

numbers = Numbers([12, 34, 56])
numbers.add(78)

numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
```

or, if you really have to, at least make sure to pass all the arguments to the parent constructor:

```py
import pickle

class Numbers(set):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

numbers = Numbers([12, 34, 56])
numbers.add(78)

numbers = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(numbers, protocol=3))
```